# DFS Graph Traversal to print all possible paths without missing any contributing edge

Tags: algorithm, search, graph, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I want to traverse a graph to extract all the possible paths from a node to another.  I found the DFS may missing some paths I want to maintained.
For example, in the graph, I want to traverse the path from node 1 to node 5. The DFS seems to only get 1-> 2 -> 3 -> 5, without getting the 1-> 2 -> 3 ->4 ->2 -> 3 -> 5. Becuase when visiting node 4, its successor node 2 is vistited already. However, I also want the second path since I care about every possible contributing edge like 3 -> 4 and 4 -> 2.

Currently, I just maintained lots of incomplete paths like 1->2 ->3 ->4 without the next part to the destination. To complete them, I tried to find the node 2 and concatenate it with the paths starting from node 2. I am not sure if it is the right solution. It seems still missing some possibilities. Is there any standard algorithm serving for this purpose?
[image]

Comment: I think that code ([mcve] ) would have been clearer and shorter than the attempt to describe it.

Comment: In DFS you typically keep track of visited nodes. Why not instead keep track of visited edges.

Comment: @MarkMeyer But in the example case, the edge 2 -> 3 also need to be visited twice. In other case with more loops, some edge may also need to be visited multiple times

Comment: If you allow cycles, then there is a countable infinity of paths because you can traverse the cycle any number of times. You'll need to describe what you want more carefully. When you've done that, you'll probably be able to answer the question yourself. Note that even suitably restricted t avoid looping forever, even a small graph can have an enormous number of paths.

Comment: @Gene Thank you. I am also aware of this issue in my description. Actually, what I want is to miss as few valuable edges as possible. However, it may require some edges or nodes to be collected multiple times.  It may require a more strict and formal problem statement.

Comment: Yes the first step in designing an algorithm is to settle on a definition of the inputs and outputs. You haven't clearly stated what the output should be. One possibility is "all paths that don't traverse the same cycle more than once." This at least well-defined, though I think not simple to do efficiently.

Comment: @Gene Is there any algorithm serving for that purpose? the same cycle doesn't be traversed more than once?